# Looping through string in XML format in C#

Tags: c#, xml

My givens are

```
int random = 3;
string xml = "<Numbers> <Num>1</Num> <Num>2</Num> <Num>3</Num> <Num>4</Num><Num>5</Num> </Numbers>";
```

I want to iterate through this string and find if random is a number between `<Num></Num>`. Is there a way of doing this in C# Visual Studio?

Comment: Is your `string xml` supposed to be xml, cause that isnt xml...

Comment: ...and after the edit it's not valid code. Please show us a [mcve].

Comment: No its just supposed to be a string in the form of an xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XDocument you can easily query and check if the numbers exist in your XML.

```
  // XML content
  string xml = "<Numbers>" +
                  "<Num>1</Num>" +
                   "<Num>2</Num>" +
                   "<Num>3</Num>" +
                   "<Num>4</Num>" +
                   "<Num>5</Num>" +
                "</Numbers>";
```

load string into XDocument. If you read from file use `XDocument.Load(pathname)` instead.

```
  var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

check if the random number exists.

1. Take all elements from Numbers
2. Select the value inside it
3. Convert the results to string array
4. Check if the array contains the random number

   ```
   int random = 3;
   bool exists = doc.XPathSelectElement("Numbers")
     .Elements()
     .Select(x => x.Value)
     .ToArray()
     .Contains(random.ToString());
   ```

Make sure to include those namespaces

```
     using System.Xml.Linq;
     using System.Xml.XPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to do it, the simplest would probably be to use `IndexOf`:

```
if(xml.IndexOf("<Num>"+ random.ToString() + "</Num>") > -1)
{
    // found it!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse your XML to an `XElement` and query the numbers to a list:

```
var numList = XElement.Parse(xml)
    .Elements("Num")
    .Select(x => (int) x)
    .ToList();
```

And then check if your `random` number is in that list:

```
numList.Contains(random);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zS7LK5) for a demo.

Answer (score -1):

In this link you got an easy way to read through an XML: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx

If you just need that specific value you can stick with Zohar Peled's answer.